# App activities in Google

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm working on Android project with Google+ feature. I'm reading an article here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities

I understand sample below code:

```
ItemScope target = new ItemScope.Builder()
      .setUrl(targetUrl)
      .build();
Moment moment = new Moment.Builder()
      .setType("http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity")
      .setTarget(target)
      .setResult(result)
      .build();
```

But I don't know the below code, **what is the purpose of the setUrl?**

```
ItemScope rating = new ItemScope.Builder()
      .setType("http://schema.org/Rating")
      .setRatingValue("100")
      .setBestRating("100")
      .setWorstRating("0")
      .build();

ItemScope result = new ItemScope.Builder()
    .setType("http://schema.org/Review")
    .setName("A Humble Review of Widget")
    .setUrl("https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review")
    .setDescription("It is amazingly effective")
    .setReviewRating(rating)
    .build();
```

And I have seen source of the link : https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review. It contain name, reviewRating,... **Why we need "setname", "setRatingValue",....**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Review</title>
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<section>Name: <div itemprop="name">A Humble Review of Widget</div></section>
<section>
  <a itemprop="url" href="https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review">
    A link to this review</a>
</section>
<section>
  Text:
  <p itemprop="text">It is amazingly effective at whatever it is that it is supposed to do.</p>
</section>
<section itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <span itemprop="worstRating">0</span> to <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span> rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">100</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL would be a page on your site that represents the specific activity that happened. The page on your server should contain the correct Schema.org markup for the activity that is being created. The review example is just an example and you can add or remove any attributes you want as long as you conform to the Schema.org standard.

Comment: Thanks abraham, but when I change name in "setname",..., it seems notthing changed in Google App Activity?

Comment: There are a number of possibilities. If you include a URL, I believe the attributes on the page override those set through the API. `setName` will probably only work on itemtypes that support a name attribute. Name might actually be getting saved but just not getting shown in the UI, maybe the activity will have it through the API.

Comment: yeah, got it. And how can I get back a review of a user? (rating,...). A little confused,  how does user see average of review in the Google Search Result Page?

Comment: It seems google save the review for the "target url" with the "result url" only in 1 time. After that, when user change review (or something else), the moment on app activity will be updated (not created new moment).

Comment: These activities are not integrated with search results. A general product page with averaged reviews would have to be indexed by Google for that.

Comment: Can you send to me a demo page for reviewActivity in "a general product page". I have nothing when search about that!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review is an example of a review activity.

Comment: In my knowledge, the review that I have submit to link result will be indexed by google. I have changed name, text, rating,...(use "setname", "setReviewRating") but when I go to the result link: developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review, the result is always the same as the first(the rating is still "100",the name is also "A Humble Review of Widget",...). A lot of user will also review like that, how someone can see all review because there is the difference review name and text by each user?

Comment: The info is going to be pulled from the result link page, if you are just using the example link, it will always be that info.

Comment: @  Hao Tran can you please tell me how to implement this review activity..,i tried my best but m not getting it,and on google also not much inforamtion is present.please can you help me